# Stripe embedded checkout using React Router loader returning 401 status

Tags: react-router, stripe-payments

I've been following the documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/embedded/quickstart?client=react&lang=node and https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=embedded-checkout to implement an embedded checkout form using Node/Express and React.

Based on this, I have the following code (front-end modified slightly to use React Router v6 loaders rather than `useEffect()` as in the example code)...

Back-end:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`);


router.post('/create-payment-session', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orderId = req.query.order_id;
    const orderData = await db.getOrderById(orderId);

    // Generate checkout session Price objects (line items)
    // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=embedded-checkout#create-checkout-session
    const orderItemsData = orderData.order_items.map(item => {
      return {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: item.product_name,
          },
          unit_amount: (Number(item.product_price.substring(1)) * 100),  // Price in cents
        },
        quantity: Number(item.product_quantity),
      }
    });

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      ui_mode: 'embedded',
      line_items: orderItemsData,
      mode: 'payment',
      return_url: `${process.env.FRONT_END_BASE_URL}/checkout/${orderId}/payment-return?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    });
  
    res.send({clientSecret: session.client_secret});

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});


router.get('/payment-session-status', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
  res.send({ status: session.status });
});
```

Front-end:

```
import { useLoaderData, useRouteLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { EmbeddedCheckoutProvider, EmbeddedCheckout } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

import InlineErrorPage from "../../components/InlineErrorPage/InlineErrorPage";


// https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/embedded/quickstart?client=react&lang=node
// https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=embedded-checkout#mount-checkout
const stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`);

export async function paymentSessionLoader({ params }) {
  // https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#loading-data
  // https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader
  try {
    // Create a Checkout Session as soon as the page loads
    const baseEndpoint = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/checkout/create-payment-session`;
    const res = await fetch(`${baseEndpoint}?order_id=${params.orderId}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    });
    console.log(res);

    if (res.ok) {
      const data = await res.json();
      return { clientSecret: data.clientSecret };
    }
    throw new Error("Unexpected status code.");

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { error: "Sorry, payment is not currently possible. Please try again later." };
  }
}

export function PaymentPage() {

  const authData = useRouteLoaderData("app");
  const { clientSecret, error } = useLoaderData();
  console.log(clientSecret);

  if (!authData.logged_in) {
    return <InlineErrorPage pageName="Order details" type="login_required" loginRedirect="/orders" />;
  } else if (error) {
    return <InlineErrorPage pageName="Order failed" message={error} />;
  }

  return (
    <div id="checkout">
      {clientSecret && (
        <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider
          stripe={stripePromise}
          options={{clientSecret}}
        >
          <EmbeddedCheckout />
        </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

My test API keys are being pulled in from .env files and I've triple checked that they're correct, so I don't think this is the issue!

The initial session creation handled by /create-payment-session seems to be successful, as the route is returning a 200 status and I can see what certainly *looks* like a valid `clientSecret` when I log this on the front-end.

However, I'm receiving a 401 (Unauhorized) status code from the https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_pages/ endpoint when the embedded form is loaded (or, rather, fails to load) on the front end:

[image: console.log error]

[image: form loading error]

Strangely, in the Stripe logs, I'm seeing multiple 200 status responses but nothing referencing the 401s:

[image]

Anyone have an idea about what's going on? I'm confused because my code seems to be fundamentally the same as the example, but it's been a long day so I might be missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing all of that out, I decided to go back to the example and replicate it as closely as possible, specifically all the code concerning the front-end public/publishable API key which is where the issue seemed to be originating.

After commenting out the React Router v6 loader and instead using the `useEffect()` and `useState()` implementation described in the docs, the form is now loading. Here's my amended code (with the loader removed from my routing config):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLoaderData, useParams, useRouteLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { EmbeddedCheckoutProvider, EmbeddedCheckout } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";


// https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/embedded/quickstart?client=react&lang=node
// https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=embedded-checkout#mount-checkout
const stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`);

export function PaymentPage() {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
  const { orderId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a Checkout Session as soon as the page loads
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/checkout/create-payment-session?order_id=${orderId}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
  }, [orderId]);

  return (
    <div id="checkout">
      {clientSecret && (
        <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider
          stripe={stripePromise}
          options={{clientSecret}}
        >
          <EmbeddedCheckout />
        </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I should have just tried that originally, but honestly I'm still not too sure why the original version wasn't working. I assume it was an async issue causing the key to be sent in requests before it had been retrieved, but I'd be interested if anyone else has a more specific answer (and ideally a solution for using a React Router loader without this issue).